# DrawString Centered Text in C#

Tags: c#

Today I am trying to draw a string on a form, but need to be drawn exactly in the middle, I have sought functions but I do not see the parameters of the rectangle centered or obtained automatically.

If someone would kindly give me some function in which to center the text automatically. The commands I use are:

```
 gfx.DrawString(line, printFont, myBrush, leftMargin, YPosition(), new StringFormat());
```

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 4):

You can set parameters using the StringFormat object you're passing in.

```
StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;      // Horizontal Alignment
stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;  // Vertical Alignment
```

[How to: Align Drawn Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332kzs7c.aspx)

Comment: I Tried this Code, But Te Rectangle is not obtained Automatically in the form  (Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 130, 140);), I need Auto detect the Form Size.

Comment: Yes, If you see first Create an Rectangle and the size parameters is not obtained automatycally. I need Get the X,Y size form the form

Comment: e.Graphics.DrawString(text1, font1, Brushes.Blue, rect1, stringFormat)
The Rect1 = Form Size, do you understand me?